# Multiple custom filters in 1 plugin?

Tags: core-image

I'm writing a few custom CIFilters for a program.  Based on the fact that CIKernel's `kernelsWithString:` will take multiple kernels from the same file (and a few similar clues I can't recall right now), it seems like I could provide them all in 1 plugin.  Am I barking up the wrong tree, or is this doable?

I made an admittedly flawed attempt at this, and the 2 filters *do* show up.  However, one was flawed, and using `[[CIFilter filterWithName:filterName] attributes]` on it produces null for the parameter list.

I believe I've fixed it now, but `[CIPlugIn loadAllPlugIns]` "loads newly added image units, but image units (and the filters they contain) that are already loaded are not removed."  Either my fix is being ignored, or I haven't actually fixed it.  Unless somebody knows a method that unloads a filter (which the Core Image Programming Guide *implies* is possible), I can't be sure without rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had a misunderstanding of how the CIPlugin system works: it is not global.  That is, each program's loaded plugins are independent of other programs'.  So to update a plugin, simply close all programs that are using it, and replace the plugin.

To answer the main issue, yes, it's fairly easy to put multiple filters in 1 plugin.

- Each filter needs it's own `XxxPlugInLoader : NSObject <CIPlugInRegistration>` class and `Xxx : CIFilter` class.  (The filters' `bundleForClass` appear to all load from the same bundle.)
- The kernels can be in the same *.cikernel file or not, but if together avoid loading the *.cikernel for each filter (it won't hurt, but it's inefficient).
- Set up 1 Description.plist and 1 Description.strings, with the info for all the filters.  In the plist, each filter's `CIFilterClass` entry must match the CIFilter class defined above.  Each filters `CIAttributeDescription` entry is a key into the strings file.